# Node.js CPU intensive high load for a script that forwards data from port to port

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with codding a `node.js` program that forwards traffic from an port to another. The scenario goes like this. I forward all traffic from port `55555` to a `sshtunnel` that have a `SOCKS5` opened on port `44444`. The thing is that everything works smoothly, until i run the command `htop -d 1` and i see high load when i am visiting 2-3 sites simoultaniously. If i go trough `SOCKS5 SOCKS sshtunnel` directly i see load at peek 1% of a core, but with `node.js` i se `22%` `26%` `60%` `70%` even `100%` sometimes. What is happening, why is this? I mean think about when i open like 1000 of those what would happen!!

Here is my first try (`proxy1.js`) :

```
var net = require('net');
require('longjohn');


var regex = /^[\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]+$/;
var regexIP = /^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/;

// parse "80" and "localhost:80" or even "42mEANINg-life.com:80"
var addrRegex = /^(([a-zA-Z\-\.0-9]+):)?(\d+)$/;

var addr = {
    from: addrRegex.exec(process.argv[2]),
    to: addrRegex.exec(process.argv[3])
};

if (!addr.from || !addr.to) {s=
    console.log('Usage: <from> <to>');
}

net.createServer(function(from) {
    var to = net.createConnection({
        host: addr.to[2],
        port: addr.to[3]
    });

    // REQUESTS BEGIN
    from.on('data', function(data){

    });

    from.on('end', function(end){

    });

    from.on('close', function(close){

    });

    // error handeling
    from.on('error', function(error)
    {

    });

    from.pipe(to);
    // REQUESTS END

    // RESPONSES BEGIN
    to.on('data', function(data){

    });

    to.on('end', function(end){

    });

    to.on('close', function(close){

    });

    to.on('error', function(error) 
    {

    });

    to.pipe(from);
    // RESPONSES END



}).listen(addr.from[3], addr.from[2]);
```

Here is my second try (`proxy2.js`) :

```
var net = require('net');

var sourceport = 55555;
var destport = 62240;

net.createServer(function(s)
{
    var buff = "";
    var connected = false;
    var cli = net.createConnection(destport,"127.0.0.1");
    s.on('data', function(d) {
        if (connected)
        {
           cli.write(d);
        } else {
           buff += d.toString();
        }
    });

    s.on('error', function() {

    });

    cli.on('connect', function() {
        connected = true;
        cli.write(buff);
    });

    cli.on('error', function() {

    });

    cli.pipe(s);
}).listen(sourceport);
```

I also tryed to run `cpulimit -l 10 nodejs proxy.js 55555 44444` also makes load and it seems like it is oppening new forks, processes ...

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

nodejs --version
    v0.10.25

processor
    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1246 v3 @ 3.50GHz with 8 cores

RAM
    32 RAM (that stays free all the time)
```

Server config :

1. Why is the load so big?
2. How can i write the code to not make that load?
3. Why 'cpulimit -l 10 nodejs proxy.js 55555 44444' dosen't work as expected?
4. Why `node.js` is using CPU and not RAM ?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Because the CPU is the responsible to execute the code, and the RAM can only open the program on it so the CPU can read from it and execute the instructions. If you like to know more about this, read a book on computer structure.

Answer (score 0):

Port is merely a segment in the memory and writing fast on ports may load the CPU because it may create too many async IO requests. However these requests are even though they are IO bound are indirectly CPU bound.

To avoid this problem you may have to limit too many connection requests by streaming data. Rather than sending 1000 small requests, make 100 large requests.

I'm not sure how to solve this or what exactly is happening. May be socket.io with streaming can help.